# after wp_insert_post need to get the post id

Tags: wp-insert-post

I have a function in function.php and it does wp_insert_post.
how can I get the post id which just posted?

when I do wp_insert_posts, it saves a PR value (unique and it saves in post-meta table).  Do I need to do "select"?
like select post_id from wp-post where oid=".$oid...... etc
like this?

I have tried to get
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        $post_id = get_post($post_id)
But these are not working.

I am not also very good at wp join. how can I do?

Comment: I just made it like this..  $newest_post_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'us_visa' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1");
is it ok after just did wp-insert-post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$post_ID = wp_insert_post($post);
```

... should work, as you mentioned. From the Codex:

> Returns the ID of the post if the post is successfully added to the database. On failure, it returns 0 if $wp_error is set to false, or a WP_Error object if $wp_error is set to true.

Comment: it comes "0".
I did $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
 // This will redirect you to the newly created post
 echo "cc=".$post_id;
like this.